# Inverse function of $2^{x(x-1)}$?

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

I tried taking log to the base $2$ both sides and solving it using quadratic formula :

$$y = 2^{x(x-1)}$$

Taking log to the base $2$ both sides :

$$\log_2(y) = x(x-1)$$

$$x^2 - x -\log_2(y) = 0$$

Solving the above equation for $x$ :

$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4\log_2(y)}}2$$

However, the answer to this question is :

$$x = \frac{\log_2(y)}{\log_2(y) - 1}$$

I would appreciate if someone can answer this question for me. It has been bugging me for a while. Btw before posting this question here, I tried to find if someone has already asked this question but no one has.

Comment: It must have been $2^{x/(x-1)}$ instead of $2^{x(x-1)}$.

Comment: @Gae.S. is correct.  The solution to $2^{x(x-1)}=y$ is not $x = (\log y)/(\log y - 1)$

Comment: The book says the latter though. Anyway, I checked and saw that the answer (posted above by me) corresponds to the former instead of the latter. So I presume it must be printing mistake by the book. I checked the book on archive.org and it has the same mistake. That kind of infuriates me since this problem gave me a headache. Anyway, thanks Gae. S. for pointing out the mistake :)

Edit:- Also, thanks to GEdgar for the reply. And yes, I checked!

Comment: The original function must be with the division in the exponent because following the reverse process given in the answer, follows that the inverse of the inverse is the function with the division in its exponent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It might be a typo in the book, indeed if we try to obtain the inverse function of $$y=2^{\frac x{x-1}}\,$$ we get the correct answer.

By taking the logarithm to the base $2$ both sides, we get that :

$$\log_2(y)=\dfrac x{x-1}$$

$$x\log_2(y)-\log_2(y)=x$$

and by solving the above equation for $x$ :

$$x\log_2(y)-x=\log_2(y)$$

$$x\big(\log_2(y)-1\big)=\log_2(y)\;\,.$$

Hence, the inverse function is :

$$x=\frac{\log_2(y)}{\log_2(y)-1}\;\,.$$

Comment: I suggest replacing the initial statement by, "It might be a typo in the book, indeed if we try to obtain the inverse function of"